# EvoSuite - Parameters For Getting Most Code Coverage

Tags: testing, junit, parameters, command, evosuite

I'm generating unit tests with EvoSuite and would like to get as close to 100% code coverage from the resulting unit tests as possible.  What are the best command line options/parameters to set to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

EvoSuite comes with its parameters already tuned. if you want to improve coverage further, you d need to increase the allotted time for test generation (eg by using -Dsearch_budget parameter), although that cannot guarantee 100% coverage. For more info, see http://www.evosuite.org/documentation/commandline/

Comment: That seemed to work well.  The default was 60 and I put 600 and went from 50% to 60% coverage.  Adding more time didn't help.  I see a lot of WARN and MASTER messages in the output.  Would finding a solution to them increase code coverage %?

Comment: For example.. [MASTER] 15:22:09.746 [logback-1] WARN  TestChromosome - Functional mock problem: org.evosuite.ga.ConstructionFailedException: Failed to add constructor for java.awt.FileDialog due to org.evosuite.ga.ConstructionFailedException: Failed to add constructor for javax.swing.JDialog due to org.evosuite.ga.ConstructionFailedException: Failed to add constructor for java.awt.FileDialog due to org.evosuite.ga.ConstructionFailedException: Failed to add constructor for javax.swing.JDialog due to org.evosuite.ga.ConstructionFailedException: Max recursion depth reached

Comment: and.. [MASTER] 15:17:48.732 [logback-1] WARN  TestChromosome - Functional mock problem: org.evosuite.ga.ConstructionFailedException: Error: VariableReference: Statement 14, type java.util.Hashtable<K, V> is not assignable to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>

Comment: and.. [MASTER] 15:17:25.415 [logback-2] ERROR TestCluster - Failed to check cache for java.util.Set<E> : Type points to itself