# How to get more (all) corner cases while Evosuite test generation?

Tags: java, evosuite

My sample target code to cover by tests looks like this :

```
public class Calculator {
  public int div(final int a, final int b) {
    if (b > 3) {
        return a/(b-5);
    } else {
        return a/(b-1);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm expecting tests with argument `b == 1` and `b == 5` are generated to uncover all possible `ArithmeticException` cases. But just this option uncovering only 1 `ArithmeticException` case is provided:

```
  @Test(timeout = 4000)
  public void test3()  throws Throwable  {
      Calculator calculator0 = new Calculator();
      // Undeclared exception!
      try { 
        calculator0.div(2232, 1);
        fail("Expecting exception: ArithmeticException");

      } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
         //
         // / by zero
         //
         verifyException("hello.Calculator", e);
      }
  }
```

(other generated tests are: `div(0, 3); div(-5, 0); div(5, 0); div(-635, 3661);`)

I've tried these run options for mvn but nothing helps: `-Dsearch_budget=600 -DtimeInMinutesPerClass=15 -Dminimize=false -Dassertion_strategy=all`

Is there a way to catch all the "tricky" test cases?

There are similar questions already:
[Evosuite generates only a few test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701654/evosuite-generates-only-a-few-test-cases) (no answer)
[EvoSuite - Parameters For Getting Most Code Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285518/evosuite-parameters-for-getting-most-code-coverage) (suggesting to use `-Dsearch_budget` parameter which doesn't work out for my case)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Nikolay. Can you share what is output for b==1 and 5?

Comment: I'm implying a developer of Calculator.div(a, b) hasn't handled correctly the corner cases when argument b is 1 or 5 which leads to division by 0 and unexpected ArithmeticException. One of the case (for b==1) is caught by Evosuite and that's really great but wanted to catch all the tricky cases.

Comment: what happened for b==5?